# How to view collapsed elements while designing a WPF control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, visibility

I set my DataGrid to collapse when there are no items

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"
          Visibility="{Binding HasItems,
                       ElementName=dataGrid,
                       Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is, I would like it to appear on design mode. How to do it? Should I create fake data?

I tried

```
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = new List<Table> { new Table() };
        }
    }
```

but it didn't work

Comment: What is the BooleanToVisibilityConverter doing?

Comment: I assume it translates true to "Visible" and false to "Collapsed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, this works well for me:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFScratch.MainWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFScratch"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"  
    d:DesignWidth="592"  
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyDesignTimeViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter
     x:Key="BoolToHiddenConverter"
     TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Hidden" />        
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>       
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
      Visibility="{Binding HasItems,
                   ElementName=dataGrid,
                   Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

```
public class MyDesignTimeViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get 
        { 
            return new ObservableCollection<Person> { 
                                                        new Person 
                                                            { 
                                                                Name = "Simon" 
                                                            },
                                                        new Person 
                                                            { 
                                                                Name = "Jack" 
                                                            } 
                                                    }; 
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in a Silverlight app where I did not want to show any content to the user until they were logged in.  I set the visibility of the View to "Collapsed" in the constructor of the View, and then back to "Visible" after the user was Authenticated/Authorized.  I suggest that you bind to the Visibility property of your Grid in the constructor of the View so that this doesn't take effect until the code executes, thereby letting you see the Grid in design view.  I haven't done much in WPF, but something like this might work:

```
Binding b = new Binding("Visibility");
b.Source = dataGrid.HasItems;
b.Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataGrid, VisibilityProperty, b);
```

Again, I have no idea if this will work in WPF, but maybe this will get you closer.